# New metatag for out-of-the-box ideas or required answers

Tags: discussion, meta

So a user wants to use a tool/material/whatever in a very odd way or has a task that requires something out of the norm.  I thought it would be good to categorize these.  I had used "weird-ideas" but I guess it wasn't liked.

So maybe "out-of-the-box" or "unconventional" or something else?  If not useful (I think it is) it is certainly interesting to see these labeled in one place.

Answer (score 3):

These are meta tags and as such aren't welcome on the site.

The main thing to consider is that:

> **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag**. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.

For more information see the blog post:

[The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: Maybe I am confused because I see tags like "tips".  Don't see how tips and unconventional are different.  Actually unconventional tells me something.  Just one example.

Comment: @DMoore - "tips" is also a meta tag.